# What to do when the system is frozen?

Tags: support, mathjax

Well, I am asking about what to do when the MathJax Freezes when you are answering or asking a question? Then you open other tab but you have no draft saved.

Is there any way to recuperate at least the text or part of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSE becomes unresponsive while I am answering questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/mse-becomes-unresponsive-while-i-am-answering-questions)

Comment: An answer of mine there answers this question; of course it is a temporary fix. Given Eric's answer there, we might have a better system at place soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new version of the MathJax preview code that is now being used on math.stackexchange.com, and I hope that it will resolve the problem you have been having.  It should also provide faster math preview and more responsiveness while typing.  It is a complete rewrite of the code that hooks MathJax into the editor, however, so be sure to report any other problems that you might have.